# Rename part of file based on list of changes with Python

Tags: python

I have a folder that is updated daily with multiple documents associated with a subcontractor-generated customer numbers included in the filename. The file names need to be changed to the naming convention of our records department who does not use the subcontract-generated customer number but their own records department-generated customer number.

example (names are actual names in the files):

```
11111-firstName-lastName_middleName-0-customerID.pdf
11111-firstName-lastName_middleName-0-customerPhoto.pdf
11111-firstName-lastName_middleName-0-customerTransactionHistory.pdf
12121-firstName-lastName_middleName-0-customerID.pdf
12121-firstName-lastName_middleName-0-customerPhoto.pdf
12121-firstName-lastName_middleName-0-customerTransactionHistory.pdf
```

The subcontractor-generated numbers are not usable by our records department. We have our own customer numbers (example 11111 (subcontractor-generated number) corresponds to our records department-generated number 34343).

I have an excel spreadsheet with column A containing subcontractor-generated numbers and their corresponding records department-generated numbers).

The records department requires that all files are renamed into the convention:

```
recordsDepartmentCusomterNumber-01.pdf
recordsDepartmentCusomterNumber-02.pdf
recordsDepartmentCusomterNumber-03.pdf
```

So the original file:

```
11111-firstName-lastName_middleName-0-customerID.pdf
```

would become:

```
343433-01.pdf
```

I was hoping to be able to write a Python script that could do this, but I'm finding it difficult to know where to start as I'm new to Python but do have a basic understanding of the syntax, data structures, etc. and haven't worked with renaming files.

Comment: Your question is almost a good one, but you stopped too early: It shouldn't be to hard to google `os.rename('fileA.pdf', 'fileB.pdf')` which will rename your file. Also you will need some string methods (like `split()`) and you should be good to go. Python should be a good choice for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the spreadsheet you can use Python's CSV library like this

```
import csv
with open('spreadsheet.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

As for renaming files you can use `os.rename()`, [this could help you.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_rename)